# meaning of "esciática" circa 1878

Tags: vocabulario, definiciones, vocabulario-médico

My great, great grandfather was serving in the US Navy in Mexico when he died in 1878.

We've had the hand-written death record translated from Spanish to English but no one seems to be able to interpret the cause of death, written as

> y manifestó que hoy a las siete y media de la mañana falleció de esciática

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They probably meant *ciática*:

> **[ciática](http://dle.rae.es/?id=98Cq7xB)**
>   Del lat. tardío *sciatĭcus*, der. de *scia* 'cadera'.
>
> 3. f. Med. Neuralgia del nervio ciático.

The condition is called nearly the same in several languages, e.g. in English it's [sciatica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sciatica).

**But how could someone die from sciatica? Are you sure the word didn't mean something else in the 19th century?**

Yes, I am 100% sure *esciatica* and *ciatica* are the same thing: sciatica.
A [search in the NTTLE](http://buscon.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUILoginNtlle) shows us that this ailment has been called like that for 500+ years (*ciatica* for Spanish dictionaries, *sciatica* for Spanish-English dictionaries):

[image]

About the "cause of death" part, it seems like "death by sciatica" was not unheard of in the 19th century. Just google `sciatica as cause of death` and you will find some info and conjectures, like those found in this [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Genealogy/comments/3xkjw8/death_by_sciatica_in_the_19th_century/).
The gist of it would be:

- Death, not because of the actual sciatica, but of complications from a surgical intervention to try alleviate the pain.
- Death from rheumatoid arthritis, which may have been mistaken for sciatic arthritis back then.

Comment: Painful as it may be, can somebody actually die of sciatica? It doesn't sound like a condition that can cause death.

Comment: Yeah, that's what we thought, too: doesn't seem like a cause of death. We have been wondering if it might be used in another sense in some contexts and in that time period. Thanks!

Comment: You can also find [a few cases of both _esciática_ and _esciatica_](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=esci%3Ftica&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000) in Spanish literature in the CORDE.

Comment: Revision 2 of the International Causes of Death gives it as a cause of death http://www.wolfbane.com/icd/icd2h.htm (1909 so close in time). It also seemed to still be in as late as version 8 of ICD but I have not found it later than that although that may just reflect my search skills or lack thereof..

Comment: I feel doubtful about this answer and would encourage you to ask on Health SE.